# What are the signs that I *shouldn't* use Ruby on Rails for a project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've started learning RoR and I really like it - but it feels like it's oriented in one specific way - a very basic MVC model. 
Which type of web application might *not* benefit from using RoR? Are there any signs I can find while planning the architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a specific technical reason not to use RoR - it's fast, clean and can probably do anything PHP does.

The only reasons I can think of are the same consideration as to any other technology : Do you have the right people, is the legacy code (if any) compatible, are you in a market that makes it easy to find RoR people to support the code, and so forth.

There's also [a nice Quora thread](http://www.quora.com/When-should-you-not-use-Ruby-on-Rails-for-a-startup) about this question :

Answer (score 0):

- If you have to install your website on a client machine that does not support rails/ruby.
- If your code needs to be maintained afterwards by people that do not have rails knowledge.